# Need to run a block of code ONLY ONCE in a state updating react component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, state-management

I have a react component index.tsx in my gaming project that has state updating variables, let's say the component refreshes everytime the user balance changes.
I'm creating a "net position" feature that on starting the game saves the user balance as reference, and then it should +/- each transaction from that reference only.
Let's say user balance at start is $5000 (in footerBalance variable), so net-position label will show the value as 0 (in netPositionBalance variable), with $5000 treated as base. Now user wins $100 on next play, his balance would become $5100 (in footerBalance variable) and net-position will become $100 (in netPositionBalance variable). 
What's happening now is that as soon as balance updates, my net-position money also updates as it's in the same component file, and net-position becomes 0. 
I want this to be fixed at the very start and the this particular code shouldn't re-render irrespective of refresh in component.

The chunk of code that fetches balance is:

```
const footerBalance = useAppSelector(state => state.app.footerUnformattedBalance); //this changes balance ie it'll give $5000, and on winning $100 it'll change to $5100
```

I need a footerBalanceAtStart variable such that I can show net-position(in variable netPositionBalance) from starting point, something like this:

```
let netPositionBalance = Number(footerBalanceAtStart) - Number(footerBalance); //it should update to $100 on gameplay
```

I want "footerBalanceAtStart" to be defined such a way that it fetches balance only once and then stays the same for entire duration of project.

Answer (score 0):

So I got the answer. Apparently I could have used useEffect here too, like:

```
const [footerBalanceAtStart, setAny] = useState(footerBalance);
```

Now it would store the value only once and won't change on it's own without it's state updating function *setAny()*